Ошибка при запуске кафки: кафка не сконфигурирована для использования с zookeeper
Я хочу запустить кафку в докере. Написал такой конфиг файл:
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOO_ENABLE_AUTH: yes
    ports:
      - 22181:2181

  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:22181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

Использовал последнюю версию кафки. Но при запуске кафки возникает ошибка:

Kafka haven't been configured to work in either Raft or Zookeper mode.
Please make sure at least one of the modes is configured.

Почему возникает эта ошибка, что я неправильно сделал в конфиге? Я хочу научиться сам конфигурировать кафку, а не использовать готовые конфиги, чтобы потом развернуть кластер кафки.

сравни какие 2 проперти нужны, и какие у тебя https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/kafka#apache-kafka-zookeeper-mode-configuration

Я прописал две указанные там проперти, но это не помогло
KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID: 1
KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:22181

Keeper не keper
